# Which of these methods are possible/more efficient

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I have a text file in the format such as this

```
ignore contents for about 8 lines
... 
       x        y         z
 - [7.6515, -10.8271, -28.5806, 123.8]
 - [7.6515, -10.8271, -28.5806, 125.0]
 - [7.6515, -10.8271, -28.5806, 125.9]
 - [7.6515, -10.8271, -28.5806, 126.8]
 - [7.6515, -10.8271, -28.5806, 127.9]
 - [7.6515, -10.8271, -28.5806, 128.9]
 - [7.6515, -10.8271, -28.5806, 130.0]
 - [7.6515, -10.8271, -28.5806, 130.9]
 - [7.6515, -10.8271, -28.5806, 131.8]
```

Is there a way to get the x,y points from the possible 35000+ lines that look like the ones above *all at once* for every line? If so, is this the best way to do it?

Or,

is it better to do use `getline` method on each line, then parse the line using boost::regex?

I need to get the x,y points and fill them into a float array.

I been using boost::regex for my needs, but it involves me taking each line at at time. I have no idea how efficient it is, so I was wondering if there is a better solution. If not, I can just continue what I been doing.

The solution has to be done in c++.

Comment: You're not being very specific.  What do you mean by _"get the x,y points"_?  And do you care about the rest of the data in the line?  Using `regex` is certainly a slower solution, since they are generic state machines whereas you have a specific structure.  Or maybe you're using the `regex` incorrectly.  You're not compiling a new one for every line, are you?

Comment: What do you mean by *better*? Regarding efficiency, if you have only about 1000 lines and you do it only once, you can use pretty much anything you feel suitable.

Comment: Updated post, basically I need to read them into an array

Comment: @AntonSavin double checking, I was way off it is actually 35k lines or more

Comment: `regex` exists for convenience, not for speed. The regular expression is interpreted. It is not compiled into machine code, so it will be 1-2 orders of magnitude slower than hand-rolled C++ code. Since that's basically all you're doing, hand-rolled code should give an enormous speedup.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey I never had to parse a file in c++ before which is why I was using reg exp. Any good guides that you may know of?

Comment: You could use `fscanf` or the `cin` methods, but I would load the entire file into memory, and then read it with a lexer. The lexer would basically have a routine for recognizing floating-point numbers, and not much else. If you do that, you find it executes very few instructions per input character.

Comment: Never heard of a lexer, but seems like you have to make it according to google. you saying use fscanf and con and make my own lexer?

Comment: From my own experience, you might find the bottleneck is the conversion from text to floating point. Please use some sort of profiler before embarking on any optimisation.

Comment: The answer depends on how far you want to go with optimizations. You could map file to memory, and pass through with a lexer as suggested by Mike, but do you actually need that speed? Is it a one time job or is it a part of some busy system? Should the code be as fast as possible or moderately fast and readable / maintainable?

Comment: @Dmitry Kuzentsov. I have no idea how to do a lexer but this would be a one time thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one answered yet so I give it a try. You didn't post your solution with regexes so I can't compare the performance. I speculate that my code may be a little faster.

```
struct Point
{
    float x;
    float y;
};

void transform_string( std::string& str )
{
    auto i { std::find( std::begin( str ), std::end( str ), '[' ) };
    std::remove( std::begin( str ), i, '-' );
    std::remove_if(
        std::begin( str ),
        std::end( str ),
        [] ( char c )
        {
            return c == ',' || c == '[' || c == ']';
        } );
}

std::istream& get_point( std::istream& in, Point& p )
{
    std::string str;
    std::getline( in, str );
    if ( !str.empty() )
    {
        transform_string( str );
        std::istringstream iss { str };
        iss >> p.x >> p.y;
    }
    return in;
}
```

The code is self-explanatory (I hope). It reads a line into string, removes hindering characters and uses `std::istringstream` to parse floats. It depends only on standard library, easy to read and its performance more than enough for one time operation ( it took ~300ms to process a file with 50k lines on my laptop ). It makes some assumptions about input and doesn't do validation. You use `get_point` similar way to `operator >>`. Hope this helps.

**UPD:**
Test program:

```
int main()
{
    std::fstream in_file { "data.txt" };
    std::vector< Point > points;
    // Some code to prepare stream, e.g. skip first 8 lines with
    // std::string tmp; for ( int i = 0; i < 8; ++i ) std::getline( in_file, tmp );
    Point p;
    while ( get_point( in_file, p ) )
        points.emplace_back( p );

    for ( auto& point : points )
        std::cout << point.x << ' ' << point.y << std::endl;
}
```

Assumption that I made: Input stream contains only data with the structure that was shown in the question. If there are, for example, other characters, empty lines, or other content, then it won't work. If this assumption is not true, please specify this in the question.

Comment: I REALLY appreciate the help, I do have questions however since I am still new to the newer c++ stuff can you explain


1) why use the std::rotate?

2) explain this part "[] ( char c )" i seen it around but never understood it

Comment: @TannerSummers, I replaced rotate with remove, this should be less confusing. `std::rotate` is useful when you need to remove a range of elements at the beginning of sequence, but in this case it was unnecessary. `[]( char c ) { ... }` this is a lambda expression syntax introduced in C++11. It creates functional object which is then passed as a parameter to algorithm. If you aren't familiar with lambda expressions I recommend you to look them up. They are very useful because they decrease amount of boilerplate code significantly. In this case you would otherwise have to create a separate func.

Comment: after running the code it's not working properly, I am trying to debug it but I am still new to all this, here is the result  -48.0061 41.6415 -66.8078 18204.004.0]

Comment: @TannerSummers, What exactly doesn't work? Note that it's supposed to be used like this `Point p; while ( get_point( your_file_stream, p ) ) { /* Do something with point e.g. store in array */ };`

Comment: you are right!. I thank you. Can I ask a few more questions? let me start by saying if I explain what is happening correctly.  The auto i part is basically getting the start and end of string, but it positions the iterator when it hits the [ part? . So to start, you remove the - between start and the [ char, after that remove_if starts at the start of the string and iterators it to the .end and every time it hits , or [, or ] it gets remove. I wrong on anything? and too add, i understand what the stream part does, but why does the string look like 18204.004.0 at end? and why leave the ] at end

Comment: @TannerSummers, Yes, you understand correctly. You are probably confused with the fact that `std::remove` and `std::remove_if` don't actually remove anything - that's normal. Instead, they place removed items to the end of the sequence. It is how they work [more info](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). In this particular case it doesn't matter because all we want is to be able to use `std::istringstream` to extract floats, and it doesn't matter what garbage there is at the end of the string.

Comment: makes sense, thank you so much @Dmitry Kuznetsov . it is hard sometimes on these forums because people vote me down or get upset when i ask questions, but as a beginner of course I will be lost. I thank you very much for your time and effort.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109614/discussion-between-tanner-summers-and-dmitry-kuznetsov).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a take using Boost Spirit X3 and a mapped file.

```
struct Point { double x, y, z; };

template <typename Container>
bool parse(std::string const& fname, Container& into) {
    boost::iostreams::mapped_file mm(fname);

    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

    return phrase_parse(mm.begin(), mm.end(),
            seek[ eps >> 'x' >> 'y' >> 'z' >> eol ] >> // skip contents for about 8 lines
            ('-' >> ('[' >> double_ >> ',' >> double_ >> ',' >> double_ >> omit[',' >> double_] >> ']')) % eol, // parse points
            blank, into);
}
```

Spirit is a parser generator, so it generates the parsing code for you based on the expressions (e.g. `'x' >> 'y' >> 'z' >> eol` to match the header line).

Unlike regular expressions, Spirit knows how to deal with and transform the values, so you can then use with e.g. `vector<Point>`:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Point> v;

    if (parse("input.txt", v)) {
        std::cout << "Parsed " << v.size() << " elements\n";
        for (Point& p : v) {
            std::cout << "{" << p.x << ';' << p.y << ';' << p.z << "}\n";
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    } 
}
```

### Full Demo

Here the program parses *itself* with the sample data from your question embedded:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46d94b41ceda08e6)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>

struct Point { double x, y, z; };

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Point,x,y,z)

template <typename Container>
bool parse(std::string const& fname, Container& into) {
    boost::iostreams::mapped_file mm(fname);

    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

    return phrase_parse(mm.begin(), mm.end(),
            seek[ eps >> 'x' >> 'y' >> 'z' >> eol ] >> // skip contents for about 8 lines
            ('-' >> ('[' >> double_ >> ',' >> double_ >> ',' >> double_ >> omit[',' >> double_] >> ']')) % eol, // parse points
            blank, into);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Point> v;

    if (parse("main.cpp", v)) {
        std::cout << "Parsed " << v.size() << " elements\n";
        for (Point& p : v) {
            std::cout << "{" << p.x << ';' << p.y << ';' << p.z << "}\n";
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    } 
}

#if DATA
ignore contents for about 8 lines
... 
       x        y         z
 - [7.6515, -10.8271, -28.5806, 123.8]
 - [7.6515, -10.8271, -28.5806, 125.0]
 - [7.6515, -10.8271, -28.5806, 125.9]
 - [7.6515, -10.8271, -28.5806, 126.8]
 - [7.6515, -10.8271, -28.5806, 127.9]
 - [7.6515, -10.8271, -28.5806, 128.9]
 - [7.6515, -10.8271, -28.5806, 130.0]
 - [7.6515, -10.8271, -28.5806, 130.9]
 - [7.6515, -10.8271, -28.5806, 131.8]
#endif
```

Prints

```
Parsed 9 elements
{7.6515;-10.8271;-28.5806}
{7.6515;-10.8271;-28.5806}
{7.6515;-10.8271;-28.5806}
{7.6515;-10.8271;-28.5806}
{7.6515;-10.8271;-28.5806}
{7.6515;-10.8271;-28.5806}
{7.6515;-10.8271;-28.5806}
{7.6515;-10.8271;-28.5806}
{7.6515;-10.8271;-28.5806}
```

Comment: very nice! I been trying to learn boost and I was reading about spirit, I will give it a try thank you very much!